# Offline Speech Recognition on Android Wear

Tags: android, speech-recognition, offline, wear-os

I am using the `RecognizerIntent` inside an Android Wear application I am developing to obtain Free-form Speech Input.

It is working great when my phone is connected online. However, when I turn off my Internet connection on the phone, the Watch is able to recognize the speech and the correct text is displayed in the intent while processing, but afterwards it states "Didn't Catch that".

I've also tried implementing the `RecognitionListener` interface and I had the same issue.

Some of the tutorials I have tried using include:

1. [RecognitionListener interface](http://www.truiton.com/2014/06/android-speech-recognition-without-dialog-custom-activity/)
2. [Voice Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html#FreeFormSpeech)

I have the appropriate language packs downloaded on my phone. How can I solve this and fix the offline issue on my wearable device?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speech recognition requires access to Google's servers hence it won't work without a valid internet connection. It is possible in Android to download languages to work offline (Settings). Although, I'm not sure if this works with Wear.